# Aplicação PHP migração servidor windows

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou com uma aplicação num servidor com o encoding em ISO-8859-1 e estou migrando para outro servidor com window. A aplicação está funcionando, exceto pelos erros com os caracteres especiais. Dei uma pesquisada e tentei converter todos os arquivos para UTF-8 mas não consegui e são muitos arquivos, tipo 10mil. Quando faço um para teste ele funciona, mas o meu problema é esse, fazer para todos. Quem puder ajudar com a conversão ou com alguma configuração que resolva o problema mesmo sem conversão eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil manter como está o encoding na configuração do destino?

Comment: Bacco, foi isso que fiz por fim